# Why is JOOQ trying to convert the entire data set returned to a Date?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I'm just starting with JOOQ. I'm running it with Google App Engine in Eclipse. The code generation went fine, but when I try this `create.select().from(CLIENT_MASTER).fetch();`, I get the below error.

```
org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [select `admin_kpi`.`client_master`.`client_id`, `admin_kpi`.`client_master`.`first_name`, `admin_kpi`.`client_master`.`last_name`, `admin_kpi`.
ASASD2FDFDWhat is your name?    abcdedsad0PinnacleA3Z2UiBLQsCgSDh
210.89.56.250active2013-11-28 14:52:48enableyadmin_pinnacle_mr123456789123122
2014-12-30
0000-00-00310' can not be represented as java.sql.Date
    at org.jooq.impl.Tools.translate(Tools.java:1941)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultExecuteContext.sqlException(DefaultExecuteContext.java:659)
    at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl$CursorIterator.fetchOne(CursorImpl.java:1556)
    at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl$CursorIterator.hasNext(CursorImpl.java:1507)
    at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl.fetch(CursorImpl.java:329)
    at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl.fetch(CursorImpl.java:282)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.execute(AbstractResultQuery.java:282)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:348)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetch(AbstractResultQuery.java:312)
    at org.jooq.impl.SelectImpl.fetch(SelectImpl.java:2705)
    at com.cbcdashboard.live.DailyReportServlet.doGet(DailyReportServlet.java:33)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:128)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:48)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:95)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:508)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Value '1MrPinnacleMRc-4 yashonandan parkamericaVadodara5390016    1323131232mr
ASASD2FDFDWhat is your name?    abcdedsad0PinnacleA3Z2UiBLQsCgSDh
210.89.56.250active2013-11-28 14:52:48enableyadmin_pinnacle_mr123456789123122
2014-12-30
0000-00-00310' can not be represented as java.sql.Date
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1056)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetRow.getDateFast(ResultSetRow.java:134)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.BufferRow.getDateFast(BufferRow.java:698)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getDate(ResultSetImpl.java:2108)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getDate(ResultSetImpl.java:2060)
    at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl$CursorResultSet.getDate(CursorImpl.java:709)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultBinding.getDate(DefaultBinding.java:1972)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultBinding.get(DefaultBinding.java:1349)
    at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl$CursorIterator$CursorRecordInitialiser.setValue(CursorImpl.java:1640)
    at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl$CursorIterator$CursorRecordInitialiser.operate(CursorImpl.java:1611)
    at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl$CursorIterator$CursorRecordInitialiser.operate(CursorImpl.java:1576)
    at org.jooq.impl.RecordDelegate.operate(RecordDelegate.java:128)
    at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl$CursorIterator.fetchOne(CursorImpl.java:1540)
    ... 45 more
```

It looks like it's trying to take data returned by all fields and convert the entire string to a java.sql.Date? Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Code

```
   try (Connection connection = getConnection()) {
        DSLContext create = DSL.using(connection, SQLDialect.MYSQL);
        Result<Record> results = create.select().from(CLIENT_MASTER).fetch();
        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();
        for (Record result : results) {
            writer.println(result.getValue(CLIENT_MASTER.COMPANY));
        }
    } catch (SQLException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to connect to mysql", e);
    }
```

Table

```
CREATE TABLE `client_master` (
  `client_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `company` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `address1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `address2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `zipcode` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `phone_number` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `group_member` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `user_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `accountno` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `security_que` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `security_ans` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `payment` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `store` text,
  `inventory` enum('xx','xx') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'xx',
  `activation_code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ip_address` text NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('active','inactive') NOT NULL,
  `register_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `enable_desable` enum('enable','desable') NOT NULL,
  `is_delete` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `data_base` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `secret_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `licence_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `tokon_no` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `exp_date` date NOT NULL,
  `c_token` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `sub_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `pac_exp_date` date NOT NULL,
  `pac_amount` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `act_store` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `def_store` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `is_full_sync` enum('0','1','2','3') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `eng_flag` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `upg_flag` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`client_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=418 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

XML file for creating JOOQ classes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<configuration xmlns="http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.8.0.xsd">
  <!-- Configure the database connection here -->
  <jdbc>
    <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
    <url>jdbc:mysql://xx.xx.xx.xx:3306/admin_kpi</url>
    <user>xx</user>
    <password>xx</password>
  </jdbc>

  <generator>
    <name>org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator</name>

    <database>
      <name>org.jooq.util.mysql.MySQLDatabase</name>
      <inputSchema>admin_kpi</inputSchema>
      <includes>.*</includes>
      <excludes></excludes>
    </database>

    <target>
      <packageName>xxxxx</packageName>
      <directory>xxx</directory>
    </target>
  </generator>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Please show the code used and the full stacktrace

Comment: Add larger code snippet and full stacktrace

Comment: Could you perhaps also post the generated `TableImpl` implementation for `CLIENTMASTER`? What particular column is causing this problem? Note, in any case, you should only select `CLIENT_MASTER.COMPANY` if that's the only column you really need from the database

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I tracked down that reason of this behaviour are `0000-00-00` as a value of some date column and `conn.getZeroDateTimeBehavior() == ConnectionPropertiesImpl.ZERO_DATETIME_BEHAVIOR_EXCEPTION`.